# Most efficient fix for an edgecase PHP bug, parse_url no scheme

Tags: php, php-7.1

I've recently run into a bug in PHP 7.1 which seems to have come back after being [fixed in PHP 5.4.7](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

The problem is simply that if you pass a url to `parse_url()` and the url doesn't have a scheme it will return the whole url as if it's just a path. For example:

`var_dump(parse_url('google.co.uk/test'))`

Result:

`array(1) { ["path"]=> string(12) "google.co.uk/test" }`

While in reality here it should split into its domain and path.

I run parse_url a few ten million times a day as part of url decryption / encryption functionality. I'm looking for a fast way to fix this edgecase bug or have a reliable alternative to parse_url.

**Edit:**

Thanks for the helpful responses, here's the solution I used in the end, I hope it helps someone. I won't submit it as an answer because I already marked someone else as correct (which they are) which allowed me to write this.

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url($uri);
// if the uri has no scheme, it won't think there's a host and will give bad results
if ($parsedUrl !== false && !isset($parsedUrl['host'])) {
  // double slash prepended will parse $uri as if it has a schema and no schema will be in the result
  $parsedUrl = parse_url('//' . $uri);
}
if ($parsedUrl === false) {
  throw new MalformedUrlException('Malformed URL: ' . $uri);
}
// use parsed url as needed
```

Comment: 1: that's not a valid url, so why would you expect it to be treated as such? 2: if you look at what you linked you'll notice that it doesn't say that a url schema can be completely omitted, only that it will interpret an url starting with `//` as valid (but it won't return a schema)

Comment: first of - I disagree with this being a bug. It ist just not possible to know if the first part is a folder name (part of the path) or a domain name. This is why the schema is important.

Comment: further it does split fragments and queries from your path

Comment: So how do you efficiently patch these cases? You conditionally prepend a string to the url so that it can be parsed normally. ...right?  I'd need to see more details about the inputs.

Comment: this depends on how you get this data - if it is provided by users - then reject it because it is not a valid url!

Comment: @wodka the users input a domain, so it is valid there, just not what the function was expecting apparently. For anyone who's interested I'll edit my question to contain the solution I actually used.

Comment: I should clarify, this function is used by far more than just a user forum, data scrapers pull millions of urls in. But it's also used for user submitted stuff, which is where this error was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse_url` needs to have information if the given string is the beginning of a url.

this is why `parse_url('//domain/path')` works -> it will just not output any schema.

now to describe the problem you want to be solved: php would need to know every domain there is and to then be able to decide if this is what the user wanted (basically impossible)

Take for example the following url: 'http://whois.domaintools.com/test.at' -> if I only pass the path it will write 'test.at' -> is this now a path or domain?

Comment: I don't see this as a "solution". It explains the challenge.

Comment: there is no solution except to go back to the source of the "string" -> and figure out the original intention. this is why I have the example with the domaintools website